# How can I embrace the content of all cells in a column with brackets?

Tags: excel

I need to embrace all my cells content with { } for a tool I would like to use.

How can I do this?

Note that the content is not a number, but a string instead

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Can you give an example of what it looks like now and then how you want it to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
="{" & A1 & "}"
```

And then dragging down to perform the formula on all of the cells you need.

You can then Copy those values and then `Paste Special -> Paste as Values` to get the actual text, rather than the formula.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to copy the data to a new column or row (or even new sheet) using a function such as:

```
=CONCATENATE("{", A1, "}")
```